# PYTHON: Drawing image in tkinter bug:" type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open'"

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I downloaded Pillow (Pill) on my computer..

A bug comes when trying to draw a image in tkinter.

I've tried using Pillow (PILL) in tkinter to draw a image

```
     from PIL import Image, ImageTk

     self.img = Image.open("10d.jpg");
     self.tatras = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)
     canvas.create_image(10, 10, anchor=NW, image=self.tatras)
```

**Error:**

> type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open'

Comment: Did you name a variable `Image` somewhere in your code?

Comment: May i see the output of: `print(type(Image))`

Answer (score 0):

use the import Image as (any name you like)
and then use the name as the Image